# Vue js - :v-for loop is not iterating through array to create list items

Tags: arrays, list, vue.js, templates, v-for

I am struggling to get my v-for loop to create a list based on the size of an array. I thought it was straight forward but am having a hard time figuring out where I've gone wrong. I can only seem to get it to produce the first list item. Any ideas? When I inspect in dev tools I see the following: [image]

.vue:

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <li :v-for="item in items">item
        </li>
    </ul>
   
</template>

<script>

export default {

    data(){
        return{
            items: [
                {name: 'item1'},
                {name: 'item2'},
                {name: 'item3'},
                {name: 'item4'},
            ]
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `v-for` is a directive and it's automatically bound to the expression without using the binding sign `:`, also you should wrap the `item` with `{{}}` in order to be rendered:

```html
  <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.name">{{item.name}}</li>
```

Comment: As soon as I remove the colon I get a red squig under the whole line and I get the following error: 'Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives.'. Tried with {{item.name}} as well. The way I posted in my question is the only way I can get it to compile, but it still doesn't work properly.

Comment: add the key prop like `<li v-for="item in items" :key="item.name">{{item.name}}</li>`

Answer (score 1):

**One observation :** The colon (:) is a shorthand for v-bind. Meaning, you are binding a property to the element. But in our case we are going to iterate the array instead of binding any data.

**Working Demo :**

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    items: [
      {name: 'item1'},
      {name: 'item2'},
      {name: 'item3'},
      {name: 'item4'},
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.name">
        {{ item.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Why do I need this :key="item.name" ? The tutorials I've been watching (I'm new to Vue) never mentioned using this.

Comment: As per the vue.js Doc - The key special attribute is primarily used as a hint for Vue's virtual DOM algorithm to identify vnodes when diffing the new list of nodes against the old list. Please do upvote and accept this answer if it helps you.